# Parse comma separated list java

Tags: java, list, token

I have a list

```
List<List> rows = (List<List>) responseMap.get("data");
[[FRPP, PE103, , USD], [FRPP, PE313AHMR, , USD]
```

And I want to set the data to the fields of a bean (which represents all the fields for each line)

```
ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Bean line = new Bean();
    line.setField1("element1");
    line.setField2("element2");
    line.setField3("element3");
    line.setField4("element4");
    data.add(line);
}
```

How can I do that?

Using JDK 1.6, Windows

Comment: can you please make it understandable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting list in the format of `[[FRPP, PE103, , USD], [FRPP, PE313AHMR, , USD]`.
Use `ArrayList.get(int)` to get value of each index value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
 Bean line = new Bean();
 ArrayList al=(ArrayList)rows.get(i);//now [FRPP, PE103, , USD]
 line.setField1((String)al.get(0));//FRPP
 line.setField2((String)al.get(1));//PE103
 line.setField3((String)al.get(2));// 
 line.setField4((String)al.get(3));//USD
 data.add(line);
}
```